# search property and key value from artifactory

Tags: artifactory-query-lang

I have a aql search, I wanted to include property value from this search

items.find({"type":"file","$and":[{"repo":"abc-prod"}]).include("repo","property.*")

For above query, results are listing all key values from properties.I am looking for
results filtered with   "key" : "123.version"